# Laravel storing data using SOAP API

Tags: laravel, api, soap, soap-client

I hope some of you guys can help me I'm new to SOAP API and having rough time.

I'm using my client's database (database using soap api), my admin side or backend is laravel. I'm having some trouble with storing data using soap api to my client's database. I've already connected my laravel to their database. I was able to store data using the wsdl URL from my client using SOAPUI software.

Basically, I created a `TestController` in Laravel

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use SoapWrapper;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Helpers\SoapHelper;

class TestController extends Controller
{

private $client;

    public function index()
    {
        $result = $this->client->CreateMember(
            [
                'CreateMemberRequest' =>
                array(
                    'siteId' => '1',
                    'membership' =>
                    array(
                        'membershipId' => '',
                        'termId' => '',
                        'memberNumber' => '',
                    ),
                    'personal' =>
                    array(
                        'title' => '',
                        'firstName' => '',
                        'middleName' => '',
                        'lastName' => '',
                        'preferredName' => '',
                    ),
                ),
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

The siteId is "1" but when I input it the error shows **"SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: object has no 'siteId' property"**

NEEDS SOME HELP

Comment: Where is `$this->client` coming from?

Comment: Their's "private $client;" I forgot to include here on my question.

With regards to your question, it's in the Helper. Here's the part of my Helper

```

$header = new \SoapHeader($namespace, "loginDetails", $credentials);
        $client = new \SoapClient(
            $wsdl,
            array(
                'trace' => true,
                'stream_context' => stream_context_create($opts)
            )
        );
        $client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

        return $client;
```